# Why CIDR mask /32 required with static IP address assignment on loopback?

Tags: linux, networking, wireless-networking

I had just one question answered here regarding why a CIDR mask of /24 (or /16) must be specified when assigning a static address manually to an interface: [Why subnet prefix is required when setting up a static address with nmcli in Linux?](https://superuser.com/questions/1562380).

However, I am still confused why the /32 mask works in this case which has worked perfectly fine with one of our servers. The firewall has a port forwarding setup to this manual static IP address and anybody on the internet/LAN can connect to the server regardless which interface is currently in use - `en` or `wl`.

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
     post-up /sbin/ip addr add 192.168.1.200/32 dev lo
```

If I replace /32 with /24 (this is our LAN's scope) the connection cannot be established.

QUESTION: why this CIDR mask works in comparison to the logic presented in the other superuser question (i.e. /24)? And why if I replace /32 with /24 the connection is broken?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking. Are you aware a /32 equates to a netmask of 255.255.255.255  = a single IP.  If you had a netmask of /24, the network would be defined by the range 192.168.1.0-192.168.1.254, so the IP range would need to be 192.168.1.0.   If you had a netmask of /30 this would be accepted (but wrong because it would define the range 192.168.1.200 - 192.168.1.203)

Comment: Well, the confusion is due to a few things explained in https://superuser.com/questions/1562380. Seems to be inconsistent logic?

Comment: I've skimmed that post. I don't see any inconsistent logic. What do you perceive as inconsistent?